# Representation Theory on Hilbert spaces

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups

Are there any good references on representation theory of Lie groups on infinite-dimensional vector spaces, or more specifically, unitary reps on Hilbert spaces? Some application in physics would be nice if possible.

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Unitary_group_representations_in_physics.html?id=u2kPAQAAMAAJ

Comment: In the compact case things are quite nice because of the Peter-Weyl theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem) and you can search for references using that keyword. In the noncompact case things are much more complicated even for $G = SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ (the subject of an entire book by Lang!), and there are infinite-dimensional unitary irreducibles and so forth. Are you interested in the noncompact case?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Peter-Weyl seems very interesting. Any recommended references? I'm interested in both compact ($SO(n)$) and noncompact (Poincare group) cases, but probably can start with compact cases.

Answer (score 0):

Brian C. Hall: *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction* (Graduate Texts in Mathematics)

Comment: I have read parts of this textbook before. Though it is definitely a great book, I'm don't think it deals with infinite-dimensional representations.